# Convert a list to a map and get item in one line

Tags: scala, dictionary

Try:

```
(List(('c', 1)).toMap)('c')
```

Error:

```
found   : Char('c')
required: <:<[(Char, Int),(?, ?)]
```

However, this works fine:

```
val m = List(('c', 1)).toMap
m('c') // gives 1 as expected
```

Why would it matter whether to store it first in a variable or not? Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the full signature of `toMap` is the following:

```
def toMap[T, U](implicit ev: <:<[A, (T, U)]): Map[T, U]
```

The collections API designers didn't want `List(1).toMap` to compile, so they require you to provide implicit evidence that the contents of the list are tuples.

Normally you don't have to think about this—you just call `toMap` without an argument and the compiler finds the implicit evidence. When you write something that looks like you're calling `toMap` with an argument, though, you get into trouble, because it's always *possible* to provide implicit arguments explicitly.

The easiest workaround (assuming you don't want to define a separate variable) is to call `apply` explicitly. `whatever(foo)` is just syntactic sugar for `whatever.apply(foo)` (unless `whatever` is a method), and if you write the following your code will compile:

```
scala> List(('c', 1)).toMap.apply('c')
res0: Int = 1
```

Now it's perfectly clear that you're not trying to call the `toMap` method with `c` as an argument.

Comment: nice one ! thanks for explaining it. This kind of stuff makes Scala quite frustrating sometimes

Comment: Yeah—there's a _lot_ of syntactic sugar, and when two lumps of it interact like this it can be confusing as heck. Stick with it, though—it gets better.